# Sharepoint 2013 - encapsulating Content Editor contents with HTML tags

Tags: sharepoint-2013, web-parts

**Problem**

We have to migrate another website into our company's Sharepoint 2013 environment to make all the text editable by end-users. Sounded simple enough, just use Content Editor Web Parts. However, there are some bits of text embedded in either

or header (,, etc.) HTML tags. When trying to surround the CEWP with those tags, Sharepoint either ignores them or restructures the HTML to move the Web Part outside of these tags. The group who will be editing the site doesn't know or want to know any HTML, so I cannot require that they add these tags to the text themselves.

**Question**

Is there any way to embed HTML tags into the content of a CEWP without having to require it of the user? I'd like to avoid any customized Web Parts if possible, but will do so if that's the only way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to link your CEWP with a .TXT files. That way, SharePoint will never restructure your HTML. However your end user will have to edit a HTML file containing text.

Otherwise, your end user could use "styles" from the ribbon. These can also be customized : https://knowledge.zomers.eu/SharePoint/Pages/How-to-add-custom-styles-to-the-ribbon-in-SharePoint-2013.aspx

Comment: This will work for what our users need. I especially will do the custom styles for the ribbon, I'm glad they are accessible for customization.

Answer (score 0):

I can be wrong, but you can edit the source of the CEWP contents instead of using the rich text editor ?

Comment: Yes, the contents of the CEWP can be edited, and it's easy enough to add the HTML tags <h2> <p>, etc. However, I can't expect the users to do this at all, much less in the appropriate CEWPs. I need to force the tags somehow.

Comment: You have styling options in the ribbon?

Comment: No, but I'm going to invest in adding the styles to the ribbon. Sounds like a pleasant reusable feature.

Comment: There are there by default though?

Comment: Yes, but not pre-defined. The site being migrated includes styles on paragraph tags, h1, h2, h3 tags, etc. If I can custom-define those styles in the ribbon, then that would work for me.

Comment: fair argument ;-) happy coding :)